# почему с компа не видимы программно созданные телефоном файлы и как это исправить?

Tags: android

почему с компа не видимы программно созданные телефоном файлы и как это исправить?

Comment: имеется ввиду программно созданные на телефоне

Comment: внесите правку в вопрос. Комментарии не всегда воспринимаются должным образом.

Comment: в какой папке созданные? P.S. Android Studio тут не при чем.

Comment: и созданные папки тоже не виднов папке например в тоже созданной, либо в существующей, либо в корне, нигде не видно

Comment: и созданные папки тоже не видно

Comment: Если вы их создаёте в Internal памяти, то не сможете с компа увидеть.

Comment: что зачит internal? создаю на microsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что Android-устройства подключаются к компьютеру в режиме [MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), а так, как эмeуляция MTP-устройства происходит программно, он не сразу *индексирует* новые файлы. Поэтому, нужно, например, перезагрузить дивайс для того, чтобы он проиндексировал файлы.

Также, вы можете использовать альтернативные файловые менеджеры для компьютера, например [Android Commander](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=161480)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, помогло